# Credit Memo is not working in Magento 1.8.1

Tags: sales-order, creditmemo, magento-ce

I am facing an issue while creating an Credit memo for a order. I am getting error as **"Argument 'Invoice number' not set!".**

This order has been placed through PayPal.

Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Please provide some code, so we **can** help. Do you have error logs?

Comment: See this screenshot: http://puu.sh/i86Ee/4de87b57a1.png. I don't see this in exeception log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the below code on salesOrderCreditMemoCreate function in Observer.php of klarnacheckout module.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo()->getOrder();

            $payment = $order->getPayment();

            $method = $payment->getMethod();
               $supportedMethods = array(
                'klarnacheckoutpayment'
               );
            if (!in_array($method, $supportedMethods)) {
                return $this;
            }
```

Add this code just after this line:

```
$items = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo()->getAllItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error message. The only place i could find a reference to the message was in `<magento root>/lib/Klarna/Exception.php` in the class `Klarna_ArgumentNotSetException`. This exception is thrown when the `creditInvoice` function in `<magento root>/lib/Klarna/Klarna.php` is called with an empty `$invNo`.

The source of the problem in my case was the module `Vikingweb/Klarnacheckout` which runs the `salesOrderCreditMemoCreate` function on the `sales_order_creditmemo_save_after` event. In my version of the module this function does not seem to check if the correct payment method was used so it was run for every payment method – which resulted in the `$klarnaInvoiceId` to be empty and the exception to be thrown.
I solved the problem by disabling the module, as it was not in use anymore.